# Mod Rewrite to Localhost

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a laravel application and I want the public folder to be accessible thru apache mod_rewrite. What should be my RewriteRule if I want my URL http://localhost/dev/admin to access http://localhost/dev/public/admin?

Comment: Having a `/dev` directory publicly accessible makes a `/public` directory pointless unless the `/dev` were also rewritten. I'd sooner create a subdomain on your localhost: http://dev.localhost/public/admin then add the following line to your hosts file for the fake domain: `127.0.0.0       dev.localhost` finally config apache to add the virtual host: `<VirtualHost *:80>`  
`ServerName dev.localhost`  
`DocumentRoot "C:/public_html/dev"`  
`</VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

> /dev/.htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine on

    #Because we're inside of a subdirectory
    RewriteBase /dev/

    #Handle the case of localhost/dev
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]

    #Handle the case of localhost/dev/...
    RewriteRule  ((?s).*) public/$1 [L]

    #The (?s) part is a Perl-style inline regex modifier meaning "single line"
    #so the dot will match unlikely new line characters.
    #I borrowed the idea from here:
    #https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial.html#beautiful-urls
```